# party package for decision tree in R does not support character data type?

Tags: r, decision-tree

If one of the columns in my data frame is of data type character, I get the error below.

```
> library("party")
> r2 <- ctree(Sepal.Length ~ .,data=df)
Error in trafo(data = data, numeric_trafo = numeric_trafo, factor_trafo = factor_trafo,  : 
  data class character is not supported
> plot(r2)    
> sapply(df,class)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
    "factor"     "factor"     "factor"  "character"     "factor"
```

Sometimes, I also get this error

```
 Error in match.arg(type) : 
  'arg' should be one of “response”, “node”, “prob” > 
> sapply(df,class)
          AGE        GENDER          STAY      GRADE          XYNS        CHARGE 
    "integer"     "integer"      "factor"     "integer"     "integer"     "integer"
```

How do I get around these?

Comment: Convert your character values to factors. `df$Petal.Width <- factor(df$Petal.Width)`. You can't really model arbitrary string values. You need to at least assume they are a discrete/categorical variable.

Comment: @MrFlick , thanks for the reply. But the trouble with converting to factors is that these decision tree packages are really slow with increasing the number of factors. Isn't there a way to keep them a numeric/continuous variables and use this package?

Comment: You could map the character values to numbers and use a `numeric` column vector input instead.

Comment: Have you tried using package `randomForest`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , yes I have thanks. But why are these decision tree packages slow with increasing the number of factors. I read somewhere that it has to turn each factor variable into two binary variables as it prepares the model matrix. But why is that needed? Can't it just keep it as a category and carry on creating a tree structure?

Comment: Treating something as numeric vs factor usually has a bit impact on how you interpret the results. That's not a substitute you often can easily make unless you perhaps have ordinal categorical variables. If you want to map character values to unique integer values, you can do `as.numeric(factor(...))`.

Comment: @MrFlick Good point...what I had in mind was finding a way to avoid factor while keeping the predictors as categorical variables.

Comment: @MrFlick , I would like to ask the same question as I asked Tim above. Why are  decision tree packages like say rpart slow with increasing the number of factor levels? I know it's slow because it has to turn each factor variable into two binary variables 0/1 as it prepares the model matrix. But why is that needed? Can't it just keep it as a category and carry on creating a tree structure?

Comment: That's a methodological problem. If you have questions about the statistical methods that these packages use and why they scale poorly with the number of factors, you'd get better luck on [stats.se] where such statistical discussions are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The scale of the response variable and all explanatory variables is important for two aspects of the CTree algorithm: (1) The association tests that are carried out in each node to determine which variable should be used for splitting. (2) The selection of the best split point in a given explanatory variable.

The association tests always capture "correlation" or "lack of independence" between the response and each explanatory variable. And the type of correlation measure depends on the scale of the variables involved (see this post on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144143). The variables can be numeric (or integer), unordered categorical (i.e., factor), ordered categorical, or censored (Surv objects). Selecting an appropriate variable type for a given variable in a data frame is crucial to obtain meaningful results from the tree.

Similarly, the determination of the possible binary splits in a given variable depends crucially on the scale. And `character` is not a scale for which there is a standard way how to assess correlation or splits.